# Change limit for “Mysql Row size too large”

Tags: mysql, sql

> Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.

The following Error occurs while importing the SQL file
[Error while importing the SQL file]

[image: 1]

There are many other queries in my SQL file too, maybe this problem is occurring because of them
[Here is the Link to the SQL file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uEGRqrrlTS90mnNjba-7W4Zehh-iPAFd/view?usp=sharing)

### --
-- Table structure for table `tbl_settings`

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `favicon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `footer_copyright` text NOT NULL,
  `footer_address` text NOT NULL,
  `footer_email` text NOT NULL,
  `footer_phone` text NOT NULL,
  `top_bar_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `top_bar_phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `send_email_from` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `receive_email_to` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_recent_news_footer` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `total_upcoming_tour_footer` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `total_featured_tour_footer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_recent_news_sidebar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_recent_news_home_page` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `home_title_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_subtitle_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_status_service` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `home_title_team_member` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_subtitle_team_member` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_status_team_member` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `home_title_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_subtitle_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_status_testimonial` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `home_photo_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_title_news` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_subtitle_news` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_status_news` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `home_title_client` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_subtitle_client` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_status_client` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `home_title_destination` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_subtitle_destination` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_status_destination` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `home_title_featured_package` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_subtitle_featured_package` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `home_status_featured_package` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `newsletter_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `newsletter_text` text NOT NULL,
  `newsletter_photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `newsletter_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `banner_about` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_faq` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_news` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_contact` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_search` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_terms` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_privacy` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_destination` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_team` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_payment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_payment_success` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_payment_pending` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_registration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_forget_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_reset_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_reset_password_success` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_verify_registration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_verify_subscriber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `counter_1_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `counter_1_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `counter_2_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `counter_2_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `counter_3_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `counter_3_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `counter_4_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `counter_4_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `counter_photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `counter_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `front_end_color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `paypal_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stripe_public_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stripe_secret_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bank_detail` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What can be done in this case?

Comment: First hit on Google might help: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-row-size-too-large-errors-with-innodb/

Comment: Runs well in MySQL 5.7. See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cFidHDVNzKMBzR4VNSBJ4e/0

Comment: @TheImpaler There are many other queries in my SQL file. Please try importing this SQL file and let me know the output [link]( drive.google.com/file/d/1uEGRqrrlTS90mnNjba-7W4Zehh-iPAFd/… )

Answer (score 1):

Try using MySQL 8.0. you will face no problem.

I just created your table on my MySQL 8.0.18

```
test> use test
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] completed in 29 ms
test> CREATE TABLE `tbl_settings` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `logo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `favicon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `footer_copyright` text NOT NULL,
        `footer_address` text NOT NULL,
        `footer_email` text NOT NULL,
        `footer_phone` text NOT NULL,
        `top_bar_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `top_bar_phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `send_email_from` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `receive_email_to` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `total_recent_news_footer` int(10) NOT NULL,
        `total_upcoming_tour_footer` int(10) NOT NULL,
        `total_featured_tour_footer` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `total_recent_news_sidebar` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `total_recent_news_home_page` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `home_title_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_subtitle_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_status_service` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `home_title_team_member` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_subtitle_team_member` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_status_team_member` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `home_title_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_subtitle_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_status_testimonial` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `home_photo_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_title_news` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_subtitle_news` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_status_news` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `home_title_client` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_subtitle_client` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_status_client` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `home_title_destination` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_subtitle_destination` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_status_destination` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `home_title_featured_package` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_subtitle_featured_package` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `home_status_featured_package` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `newsletter_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `newsletter_text` text NOT NULL,
        `newsletter_photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `newsletter_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `banner_about` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_faq` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_testimonial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_news` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_contact` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_search` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_terms` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_privacy` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_destination` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_team` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_payment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_payment_success` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_payment_pending` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_registration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_forget_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_reset_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_reset_password_success` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_verify_registration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `banner_verify_subscriber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `counter_1_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `counter_1_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `counter_2_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `counter_2_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `counter_3_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `counter_3_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `counter_4_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `counter_4_value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `counter_photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `counter_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        `front_end_color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        `paypal_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `stripe_public_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `stripe_secret_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `bank_detail` text NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] [HY000][1681] Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] [HY000][1681] Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] [HY000][1681] Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] [HY000][1681] Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] [HY000][1681] Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] [HY000][1681] Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[2021-04-24 23:28:00] completed in 181 ms
```

Comment: There are many other queries in my SQL file. Please try importing this SQL file and let me know the output [link]( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uEGRqrrlTS90mnNjba-7W4Zehh-iPAFd/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: Your script is for Mysql 5.6. mysql 8 cant import it

Answer (score 0):

The maximum row size for an InnoDB table, which applies to data stored locally within a database page, is slightly less than half a page for 4KB, 8KB, 16KB, and 32KB innodb_page_size settings.

which based on the error seems like , your mysql server innodb_page_size setting is set to 16K thus your row size limit is 8126.

innodb_page_size can only be configured prior to initializing the MySQL instance and cannot be changed afterward.

references :

- [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html)
- [innodb_page_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size)

you can try to run command below and check your innodb_page_size

```
show global status
```

found this interesting :

"changing a column to TEXT avoids the MySQL 65,535-byte row size limit, and InnoDB off-page storage of variable-length columns avoids the InnoDB row size limit."

so try to change varchar(255) to text for couple of columns and this solve your issue.however there are some downsides (like text is fixed size and take more space on disk and is not fully indexable)

see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=772d26dab06c331c806e2afb0a8747de)*

or combine it with `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`

alternatively you can try to split your table into two tables or try to limit size of varchar data types in your table.

Answer (score 0):

try removing '(255)' from varchar(255). The 255 character length for all varchar columns, plus text columns is adding up to a final row size > max row size allowed in your mysql db.